# Crash in systemd-shim

Tags: package-management

Today we installed Ubuntu 13.10. Now a system error occurred:

```
Systemerror
    Executable Path     /usr/lib/I386-linux-gnu/systemd-shim
    Package             systemd-shim 3+real-Oubuntu1
    Problem Type        Crash
    Title               systemd-shim crashed with SIGSEGV in do_lookup_x()
    Apport Version      2.12.5-Oubuntu2
    Arichtecture        i386
    SegvReason          reading unknown VMA
    Signal              11
    UnreportableReason  You have some obsolete packages installed.Please upgrade system-shim, gcc-4.8-base,libgcc1,libglib2.0-0,libglib2.0-data
    Upgrade Status      No upgrade log present (probably fresh install)
```

Please help! We are a total beginner!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

System errors from my experience are extremely common with Linux but doesn't necessarily mean something is wrong. lol Usually the first time I get one I will just wait and it never comes back. Just go about your way, try updating and what not. If it keeps popping up then come back.